# How to pop up Flex Panel by clicking on a GWT(or GXT) component?

Tags: apache-flex, gwt, gxt

I have a web-application whose UI is implemented in [GXT](http://www.ansaldo-sts.co.in) (ext GWT).

Now I want to switch to [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) but as the application is so large that I cannot afford to start migrating the whole application at once.

So I have decided to migrate slowly. So what I want is to bring up a Flex panel on the click of a GXT's button.

Basically the idea is how to make Flex components listen to the events generated by GXT's component.

Answer (score 1):

Flex app is ultimately an SWF and GWT gives you JavaScript; you can use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to invoke an SWF's methods from JavaScript code and vice-versa. Checkout the [addCallback](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29) method - the linked page has some sample code in it.